# From price for configurables in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price-rules

Trying to find a simple and elegant way to display a from price for configurables prior to an attribute bring set, eg size.

So on product page the price renderer would initially say From X and then drop the From once an attribute is selected.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use code like this:

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox $block */
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice $finalPriceModel */
$finalPriceModel = $block->getPrice();
$minimalPrice = $finalPriceModel->getMinimalPrice();

echo 'From: ' , $minimalPrice;
```